# Swagger proxied by haproxy can't execute requests

Tags: swagger, haproxy, websphere-liberty

I have a swagger working with a haproxy. I use built in swagger in Websphere Liberty Profile (apiDiscovery feature):

Browser -swagger.mydomain.com-> haproxy -swagger.intranet-> IBM Liberty server with Swagger

The first swagger page is generated and shown correctly in the browser, but as Liberty server gets the request from haproxy, not my browser, and gets them to the intranet name/ip (swagger.intranet), Swagger code to execute GETs, POSTs, etc. is generated with that intranet IP name (swagger.intranet), so when I try any of the methods they won't work as reference this internal ip name from in a browser outside that zone.

Can I configure haproxy with some header to inform haproxy that he should generate code with the original server name (swagger.mydomain.com) request used in the request? (That is the one to be used in the generated HTML/Javascript code)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Liberty trusts the Host: header and uses it to assemble self-referential links.

Where you define the backend, try setting     `http-request set-header Host swagger.mydomain.com` to what the client will be using or **removing** a similar stanza if you are setting it to some swagger.intranet already.

(sorry, I'm not an HAProxy user.  This is based on searching for 'HAProxy equivalent of ProxyPreserveHost')

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It turns out that the problem is not in HAProxy but in Liberty. It generates Swagger to the IP from default_host value. Localhost or swagger.intranet , but will never generate based on Host header value. It works locally, obviously, as it is always localhost, but when I deploy it in the Docker mapping the port directly without a haproxy, the problem is the same. I need to include a fake entry in my hosts file to make the browser call the correct IP. Any ideas?

Comment: Where does the bad host first appear? In a redirect, or in some HTML?

Comment: In Liberty built in Swagger. Swagger doc is generated but when I try to test a request using that swagger, the call points to Liberty default host, not the external IP name used in the original request.

Comment: I'd suggest identifying the offending HTML and reporting the bug to IBM in a PMR.